# If a system is in a state $L^2 =2 \hbar^2$ and $L_x=0$ why can't $L_z$ be 0?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, angular-momentum

A particle is in a state where $L_x=0$ and $L^2 = 2\hbar^2$. 
This means $l=1$ and $m_x = 0$.

I will call this state $Y^x_{lm} = Y^x_{10}$

I wanted to know what possible values $L_z$ could have in this state if it would be measured.

I know $L_z$ can only take the values $\hbar, 0$ or $-\hbar$ and corresponding eigenfunctions $Y^z_{11}$, $Y^z_{10}$ or $Y^z_{1-1}$

I want to write the state  $Y^x_{10}$ as a linear combination of the eigenfunctions of $L_z$.

If I rotate the coordinate system around the y-axis to put the x-axis on the z location I can prove that

$$Y^x_{10} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} (Y^z_{11} - Y^z_{1-1})$$

**Noticable** 
From the mathematics I can clearly see that a particle in state $Y^x_{10}$ can never have the value $L_z=0$.

**My questions**
Why? Is there an insightful explanation why the it cannot take a value 0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The intuitive explanation is that an eigenstate of $\hat L_x$ with eigenvalue $m_x=0$ is invariant by rotation around the $x$ axis (by definition), but not by rotations around any other axis. Thus it cannot be an eigenstate of $\hat L_z$ with eigenvalue $m_z=0$. See for example this picture of the eigenfunctions of $\hat L{}^2$ and $\hat L_x$ :[image]